# Wordpress Redirect IP to URL and URL to IP (Stuck in Loop)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I was developing my website over IP now I got the domain and after changing the
site_url in wp_config.php file
Reference
https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/

It keep on redirecting me From URL to IP and Ip to URL.I tried to debug and put some php code in index.php file

(Wordpress Multisite

Htaccess file

`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# WP Maximum Execution Time Exceeded
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
        php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
</IfModule>
```

`

Comment: There is nothing wrong in that configuration file. Most likely you have some cached results on the client side that still hold the address. Have a try testing with a fresh, anonymous browser window.

Comment: And a general hint: instead of using a raw IP address when developing something use a qualified host name right away. You can easily configure a local name resolution for that , just enter the name into your `hosts` file. That way you don't even have to change the name later on, you just change (remove) the local name resolution one the DNS records have been saved. This also allows to keep your local development environment in parallel while operating the live site. You simply keep to local name resolution to point to the local dev setup instead of the live site.